# UIButton selector is throwing 'unrecognized selector' even though selector exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am creating 2 buttons programmatically in my view.  Both selector methods exist but it is still throwing 'unrecognized selector' errors.  I read something about checking for zombies.  But I activiated it (xcode 4.2) and didn't see anything about any zombies.  Here is the code..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    for(int i = 0; i < [list count]; i++){  

     ... if statement checks to add text fields
    }

     UIButton *submit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
     [submit addTarget:self action:@selector(submission:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [submit setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     submit.frame = CGRectMake(x+ 170.0, y, 72, 37);

    UIButton *addition = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [addition addTarget:self action:@selector(addition:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [addition setTitle:@"Additional Mission" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    addition.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 37);

    y = y+90;
   [inputsView addSubview:submit];
   [inputsView addSubview:addition];
   [inputsView setScrollEnabled:YES];
   [inputsView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, y)]; 


}

 - (void)submission{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Submission Complete" message:@"Submission"
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert show];
}

 -(void)addition{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Creating Additional Mission" message:@"Additional Mission"
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert show];
}
```

One thing to note.. inputsView is a UIScrollView that is inside my viewcontroller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the colon from the selector methods

```
[submit addTarget:self action:@selector(submission)

[addition addTarget:self action:@selector(addition)
```

the colon tells the selector that this method takes arguments, yours do not so the colon should not be part of the selector

Comment: Ooooh.. Wow. That is embarrassing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[addition addTarget:self action:@selector(addition:)

**in this line you are saying that your selector `@selector(addition:)` expects a parameter that is a colon after addition** 
but in your real method

```
 -(void)addition{
```

there is no parameter after addition ..that is why there is a crash..remove the colon in both submission and addition and you will be good to go.